# IntelliJ IDEA inspect variable like Eclipse (Cmd-Shift-I)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I recently moved from Eclipse to IDEA and by and large have been very pleased with it. However, there is one Eclipse feature that I miss terribly after all this time: *evaluating expressions on-the-fly while debugging*.

The way debug expressions are rendered by default in IntelliJ IDEA produces very long tooltips which are kind of hard to dismiss (and more importantly very hard to read while trying to sift through the information being displayed). By contrast, Eclipse renders debug expressions using a two-pane popup window which includes a text area to display text inclusive of newlines thus making the display far more optimal (see attached pictures).

**IntelliJ IDEA**
[image: Silly IDEA Tooltip]

**Eclipse**
[image: Eclipse Tooltip]

Is this something we need to live with?

Comment: in intellij there is a debug tab besides console, there you can view all your variables if you are having a problem with tootlips, that is how i do it

Comment: I found the answer was there in the _Quick Evaluate Expression_ tool window (**Cmd-Alt-F8**). At the top of the said tool window you will find a barely visible hyperlink labelled _View_ which will display a tooltip akin to the bottom part of the eclipse tooltip displayed in the screenshot above.

Comment: Any way to use the keyboard to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **Expression Mode**, which shows tooltips

Intellij IDEA provides two evaluation methods

**Expression Mode** for evaluating single-line expressions.
**Code Fragment Mode** for evaluating short code portions. You can evaluate declarations, assignments, loops and `if/else`.

These two method can be used depending upon your situation

**Evaluating expressions or code fragments in a stack frame** (this is your case I guess)
To evaluate an expression or a code fragment in a stack frame, do the following:

1. In the Frames pane, select the thread where you want an expression
   to be evaluated.
2. Click  [image] on the Stepping toolbar in the Debug tool window.
3. Select an evaluation mode. If you want to evaluate a code fragment, click the Code Fragment Mode button.
4. Depending on the selected mode, type the expression or statements to evaluate in the text field and click Evaluate.

Go to this [Documentation Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html) for detailed instructions.

Comment: I probably didn't phrase my question clearly enough but I was alluding to the way in which IDEA renders Strings with embedded newline characters within a single line (\n) thus making the output hard to read as per my screenshot above. Compare that to the Eclipse screenshot which displays the same JSON string within a text area with newlines rendered across multiple lines thus making the output far more readable.

Comment: If you take a look at the Eclipse screenshot you'll notice that it's showing exactly the same \n which Intellij IDEA is showing and it's expected behavior because they are both interpreting it as string, not json that's why they are not converting \n into newlines, but I think Eclipse is also showing the contents of staff.json which is being converted to string, that's why you're seeing it in nice format.

Comment: In my opinion they are showing the same thing, if you want to have a clear understanding of whats going on, evaluate the expression on the right hand side of the statement, I think intellij IDEA should show it in nice format because it's json and formatting will work